# How to REJECT email using SpamAssassin

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server, spam, spamassassin

Is it possible to reject emails, like it is done in Postfix using header_checks, using SpamAssassin? Normally, the SpamAssassin only adds the spam flags and by default adds the word SPAM in the subject of the emails. But if SpamAssassin classifies a email as SPAM is it possible to tell postfix to reject that email instead of going to inbox of user account? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## In SMTP session rejects using milters

You can make postfix use spamassassin to reject messages **in SMTP session**.
It makes rejected host responsible for sending bounce notification back to sender.

Sendmail, Postfix and a few more MTA/SMRP servers support milters.
Postfix: http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html

There are a few milters supporting spamassassin to choose from:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/spamassassin/IntegratedInMta

Classic approach is to

- reject "most likely spam" in SMTP session (e.g. spam score > 10)
- mark "may be spam messages" (custom header or modified `Subject:`)

---

**Warnings**

- spamassassin tests in network mode may take **a few seconds** which is unacceptable for many MTA/SMTP servers. Local mode is faster but less accurate.

  - It **MAY** hit your server performance especially under high+ load.
  - Small minority of ham sending servers is **VERY** "impatient"
- Bayes test are crucial for very good spamassassin accuracy but they are harder to train when filtering for multiple recipients

Comment: More WARNINGS: Bouncing/rejecting spam will likely generate either "backscatter", or a hard bounce (non-existent email address) directed back at your server. The return/sender address are typically forged and may also direct back to a legitimate account. Neither one is a good thing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_(email)

Comment: Backscatter is only a problem when sending bounce messages, I believe. With a milter that rejects spam during the SMTP conversation with an SMTP error reply code this should not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
man spamass-milter
```

and note the `-r` flag.  Specify a high spam score value after the `-r` and `spamass-milter` will reject messages that score at that level or higher.

This is with `sendmail`, but I suspect your syntax will be similar:

```
spamass_milter_flags="-r 25 -R 'Message content rejected' -f -p /var/run/spamass-milter.sock -i 127.0.0.1"
```